# TypeError: __new__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'shares' and 'price'

Tags: python

I am trying to use namedtuple

```
from collections import namedtuple
Stock = namedtuple('Stock', ['name', 'shares', 'price'])

def compute_cost(records):
    total = 0.0
    for rec in records:
        s = Stock(*rec)
        total += s.shares * s.price
    return total

with open('r.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() for x in content]   
    for i in content:
         p = compute_cost(i)
    print (p)
```

It seems that I have problem,the way how I wat to use posicional arguments.

```
  File "b74.py", line 15, in <module>
    p = compute_cost(i)
  File "b74.py", line 7, in compute_cost
    s = Stock(*rec)
TypeError: __new__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'shares' and 'price'
```

And here comes my text file

```
hmf Kiza 100 2.33
piz Miki 999 0.75
air Dush 500 8.50
```

Comment: `i`/`records` is one line, no? Since you loop through it, `rec` is a single character in that line. Not sure where you think you're splitting the line into separate values.

Comment: You're feeding records to `compute_cost` one at a time, but `compute_cost` expects an iterable of records. You've lost track of what code has responsibility for iterating over the records.

Comment: Yes,so what should I change?

Comment: this error message means that you're not passing enough arguments to the Stock() constructor. Your tuples have 3 elements so you need to pass 3 arguments to the constructor. You're giving it just one argument for the reason explained by @user2357112

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message means that you're not passing enough arguments to the `Stock()` constructor. Your tuples have 3 elements so you need to pass 3 arguments to the constructor.

But in this line:

```
for rec in records:
```

`records` is a single line in your file. Therefore `rec` is just single character.

Hint: `for rec in records.split(" ")`